# C++ Windows Sockets - Close socket at program exit

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I'm making a simple console client/server application with the WinSock2 api, but I need to make sure that the socket of the client closes properly when exiting the application. I have already tried to use a `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` but that makes a thread where the main loop keeps running for 10 seconds.

Is there a way to close the socket when the user pressed the close button?

Comment: If you take no explicit action, and just close the app, does the socket not get closed by the OS process termination action?  It does with my GUI apps.

Comment: I just found out it actually did that already yes. Thanks for your help, but I am also implementing the object system as it is indeed cleaner to work with. (and thus, I am taking that as an 'accepted' answer).

Comment: You should look into [this question about RAII](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Wrap native Winsock2 socket with a class that manages it.

```
class Socket{
  SOCKET m_NativeSocket;

public:
  Socket(){
    m_NativeSocket = ::socket(...);
  }

  ~Socket(){
   ::closesocket(m_NativeSocket);
  }

};
```

You should follow this pattern because:

1. Sockets are suitable as objects, not just floating variables
2. Adding destructor makes sure that no matter if the application suddenly aborts, an exception is thrown, socket is out of scope - the socket closes properly
3. It's nicer and cleaner to work with sockets as objects.

make sure you implement proper move constructor.